# what does com attributes.LongAttribute mean?

Tags: java, javascript, php, google-ads-api

I was playing with google adwords , When i replayed one of the request in http headers , I received response with strange codes like below

```
com.google.ads.api.services.common.optimization.attributes.LongAttribute/2241574459
```

What does that mean ?is that to convert 2241574459 from long to int32 ?

Comment: check this http://search.cpan.org/dist/GOOGLE-ADWORDS-PERL-CLIENT-2.7.2/lib/Google/Ads/AdWords/v201109/LongAttribute.pm

Comment: looks like it is a type that contains a long value

Comment: hi  Mina  .. how to convert long value to human readable number ?